# How can I input a list into the collection?

Tags: c#

Can't add to collection a list of assemblers in square brackets [ ] write error!
Here is the complete class with all the collections

```
public static Random rng = new Random();
public static StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    int n = list.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }
}

public static void Generator()
{
    List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
    myStrings.Add("[assembly: AssemblyTitle(\"TITLE\")]");
    myStrings.Add("[assembly: AssemblyDescription(\"TITLE\")]");
    myStrings.Add("[assembly: AssemblyCompany(\"TITLE\")]");
    myStrings.Add("[assembly: AssemblyProduct(\"TITLE\")]");
    myStrings.Add("[assembly: AssemblyCopyright(\"TITLE\")]");
    myStrings.Shuffle();
    foreach (var item in myStrings)
    {
        builder.Append(item);
        builder.Append(" ");
    }
}
```

And try to call

```
this.textBox1.Text = AssemblyGen.builder.ToString();
        this.textBox2.Text = AssemblyGen.builder.ToString();
        this.textBox3.Text = AssemblyGen.builder.ToString();
        this.textBox5.Text = AssemblyGen.builder.ToString();
```

In the margin of the text box should get a random text

P.S: The question remained not solved

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve, or where the `Shuffle` method is meant to be coming from. Currently your code is invalid because you're not escaping the quotes properly - and it's not clear why you're using a verbatim string literal, either. That problem has nothing to do with collections though - you'd see the same thing if you had `string x = @"[assembly: AssemblyTitle("TITLE")]"`. I suspect you want something like `"[assembly: AssemblyTitle(\"TITLE\")]"`.

Comment: You need to escape your string "[assembly: AssemblyTitle(\"TITLE\")]". Verbatim String would end before TITLE and what is TITLE doing then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the quotes in your string literal:

```
myStrings.Add("[assembly: AssemblyTitle(\"TITLE\")]");
```

Furthermore, as it has already been noted, there isn't clear why you are using a verbatim string, `@`. So I have removed it from the above code.